# How to limit CPU load on mining pool

Tags: monerod, mining-pool-setup

My pool's CPU load is too high. It has a 24 thread CPU. What is a good solution to use other servers to share the load calculation or together ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try applying the help-to-your-door patch:

https://github.com/moneromooo-monero/bitmonero/tree/cache-block-template

It caches block templates, which helps mining pools a lot.

Comment: but i want develop several new server share the task A force together